# SQL Statement Termination using RAISERROR

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, triggers, raiserror

(SQL 2005)
Is it possible for a raiserror to terminate a stored proc.

For example, in a large system we've got a value that wasn't expected being entered into a specific column. In an update trigger if you write:

if exists (select * from inserted where testcol = 7)
begin
   raiseerror('My Custom Error', 16, 1)
end

the update information is still applied.
however if you run

if exists (select * from inserted where testcol = 7)
begin
   select 1/0
end

a divide by 0 error is thrown that actually terminates the update.
is there any way i can do this with a raiseerror so i can get custom error messages back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a trigger, issue a ROLLBACK, RAISERROR and then RETURN.

see [Error Handling in SQL Server - Trigger Context by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#triggercontext)

Comment: Is this only valid for a transaction? or are triggers trasactional?

Comment: From the link I posted 'When within a trigger, it is not necessary to have a matching BEGIN TRANSACTION statement because each SQL statement that is not within an explicit transaction is effectively a one-statement transaction.'

Comment: from my link: _A trigger always executes in the context of a transaction, since even if there is no multi-statement transaction in progress each INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statement is its own transaction in SQL Server, and the trigger is part of that transaction._

Comment: YEAH! your the don! Our dba hass issues with trasactions so we don't tend to research down that path, i wasn't aware that triggers fell within transactional procedures (although now you've made me think about it thats pretty obvious).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just add a **CHECK** constraint to the column to prevent it from being inserted in the first place?

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT CK_No_Nasties
    CHECK (testcol <> 7)
```

Alternatively you could start a transaction in your insert sproc (if you have one) and roll it back if an error occurs. This can be implemented with **TRY**, **CATCH** in SQL Server 2005 and avoids having to use a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

```
Begin try
@temp number
@temp=1/0
End try
Begin catch
@errormsg varchar(100)
@errormsg=error_massage()
Raiseerror(@errormsg,16,1)
End catch
```

Comment: Can you add in a description for your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should check for valid data prior to performing the update.

```
IF (@testvalue = 7)
    RAISERROR("Invalid value.", 16, 1);
ELSE
    UPDATE...
```

Comment: The data in this example is an input parameter and this shouldn't change unless the sproc explicitly changes it.

Comment: I don't know which sproc is updating this or if its a nightly database job, so i can't check the value before updating it.

Comment: Do you want this mystery job to blow up when it tries to enter this value?