# SQL2012 microsoft trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Any idea how to create a after trigger where each where each a user put in their data once. Eg. if someone put in an entry once, then it will be executed. But 2nd time i would like to say 'error message'

The tables I have a table of users, the date and their response. TABLE name is userresponse

This is my coding so far

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[prevent_multiple_entry] ON [dbo].[userresponse]
FOR INSERT
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT Users FROM userresponse) 

BEGIN 
  PRINT 'Error message'
RAISERROR('Each user can only submit to the same question once ',16,1)
ROLLBACK
END
```

Comment: Why not simply use a unique index?

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[prevent_multiple_entry] ON [dbo].[userresponse]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM userresponse AS U, INSERTED AS I WHERE U.User = I.User) 
  BEGIN 
    RAISERROR('Each user can only submit to the same question once ',16,1)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
  END
END
```

Make sure that the 'nested triggers' and recursive_triggers settings are approriate and think about the fact that allready existing data in that table won't be checked by a trigger.

And SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT sets a loophole, be carefull.

You also could define a CONSTRAINT...

Comment: you should use current style join syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172122%28v=vs.100%29.aspx  I'd also put a `RETURN` right after the `ROLLABCK TRANSACTION` just to be sure: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1239291/65223

Comment: Yes, i should be: IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM userresponse AS U INNER JOIN INSERTED AS I ON U.User = I.User)

and yes RETURN after the ROLLBACK TRANSACTION...