# Trigger in SQL to count a column and give a error if it is more than a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I need a trigger to avoid from inserting a specific value for a column , for example, in the booking table I have a bookingId and invoiceId. I want to count the bookingIds for each invoice and compare the number with a number in Airline table which called MaxBooking. if the number was more than MaxBooking it means I cannot book anymore with that invoice number.

```
|bookingId|invoiceId|passengerId|FlightId|
|1        |101      |20         |99      |              
|1        |101      |20         |99      |            
|1        |101      |20         |99      |     
|1        |101      |20         |99      |


|FlightId |AirlineId|      
|99       |500      |


|AirlineId|AirlineName    |MaxBooking|
|500      |Biritish Airway|4         |
```

Comment: The tags seem ambiguous... is this MySQL or SQL Server? What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: this is in sql and actually I'm biginner in sql and I dont have enough knowledge about triggers

Answer (score 0):

You should explain your problem better. You are probally looking for something like below. This is just a example not something to use.

```
if exists (select top 1 1 from booking b
                          join flight f on f.bookingid = b.bookingid 
                          join airline a on a.airlineid  = f.airline_id
                          join inserted i on i.bookingid = b.bookingid
                          where (select count(*) from booking bb where bb.bookingid = b.booking_id) > f.maxbooking
                               )
begin

 rollback tran

end
```

How ever there seems to be no good key on the booking table and what should you do when you at 5 rows and the max 4. Do the first 4 go trough ? That would make the query more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact solution, you are searching for

I have assumed table names to be:
1.dbo.FlightBookings
2.dbo.Flights
3.dbo.Airlines
according to their appearance in your question

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_restrictMaxBooking] 
   ON  [dbo].[FlightBookings]
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DECLARE @FlightId INT
        SELECT @FlightId=I.FlightId FROM inserted I

        IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.FlightBookings WHERE FlightId=@FlightId)<ISNULL((SELECT MaxBooking FROM dbo.Airlines WHERE AirlineId=(SELECT AirLineId FROM dbo.Flights WHERE FlightId=@FlightId)),0))
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            RAISERROR('Failed',16,1)
            RETURN
        END 
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
GO
```

Incase you need any further assistance or I am missing something, please let me know.

Comment: when a trigger detects an error you always want to do the following in order: `ROLLBACK`, `RAISERROR` and then `RETURN` http://stackoverflow.com/a/1239384/65223

Comment: it is not advised to code a trigger to only work with one row like in your code here.  If multiple rows are inserted with one command (think `insert into tableX (col1, col2) select colA, colB `) your code will only validate 1 row.